# Mapping elements attribute as member possible?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

Does someone know if there is possibility to map elements attributes to parent class/struct members?

Example:

```
<parent>
    <child id="1">
</parent>
```

I would like to have it mapped directly like this:

```
public class parent
{
    public int id;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Update:
I haven't specified it clearly, I'm looking for a solution attributes based solution that I can use XmlSerializer.

Comment: A parent always has exactly 1 child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to implement your own `IXmlSeriazliable` interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx

Here's a crude example:

```
    public class parent : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.Name == "child")
                {
                    int parseValue;
                    int.TryParse(reader.Value, out parseValue);
                    this.id = parseValue;
                }
            }
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("parent");
            writer.WriteStartElement("child");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("id", this.id.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();                
        }
    }
```

This should work with the XmlSerializer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I can solve even more complicated cases with that